# Can I skip major versions in pg_upgradecluster?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm upgrading postgresql `9.3` to `9.5` on **ubuntu/xenial** and I would like to know if it is possible to run `pg_upgradecluster` to go directly from `9.3` to `9.5` or whether I need to go through `9.4` in between?

Comment: `pg_upgrade` could certainly do that. I don't know what `pg_upgradecluster` does in the background, you would need to check that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that with `pg_upgradecluster` either way, using `-m dump` which uses `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` or `-m upgrade` which uses `pg_upgrade` according to the manpage [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pg_upgradecluster.1.html). Using `-m upgrade` should be much faster than the dump and restore method that `-m dump` uses.

Comment: Thank you, I read the manpage after your answer and the `upgrade` method was much faster!